# ACF Pro Repeater - Row Index and Total Count with Leading Zero

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

## Q&A

Here's my Q&A post for ACF Pro's repeater field and how to output the current row count as well as the total overall count, with, and without a leading zero (e.g. 1, 2, 3 vs 01, 02, 03).

### Issue 1

Using ACF Pro's repeater field, and the ACF **get_row_index** function I output a number for each item within the repeater field onto the page. (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4...) I did this like so:

```
<p><?php echo get_row_index(); ?></p>
```

I then realised the design called for a leading zero (0) in front of the number returned by the **get_row_index** function if that number is less than or equal to 9 (e.g. 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11..).

See **SOLUTION 1** below for the answer.

---

### Issue 2

Next I wanted to output the total row count, which I did like this:
**(It's important that the count function is outside of your while loop)**

```
$number_of_items = count($myRepeaterField);

<p><?php echo $number_of_items ?></p>
```

I again, then noticed the design called for a leading zero for the total count too.

See **SOLUTION 2** below for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

To output a leading zero in front of the **get_row_index** function, you can do the following:

```
<p><?php echo str_pad(strval(get_row_index()), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></p>
```

### Solution 2

To output a leading zero in front of the total **count** of items in the repeater field:

```
<p><?php if ($number_of_items < 9){echo('0');} ?><?php echo $number_of_items ?></p>
```

I hope this information helps someone, as it took a while to discover through various google searches and forum hunting.